Laravel 10 Mailable Class not rendering view files properly
I have a Mailable class in my project to send emails however I can't send emails
because it throws undefined variable error. Whats wierd is this code works locally
but not on my testing server
See details below
Mailable class

...

public function content(): Content
{
    return new Content(
        markdown: 'vendor.mail.markdown.email-verification',
        with: [
            'token' => $this->token
        ]
    );
}

...

Cached View File when Mail::send is triggered

...

@component('Illuminate\View\AnonymousComponent', 'mail::layout', ['view' => $__env->getContainer()->make(Illuminate\View\Factory::class)->make('mail::layout'),'data' => []])
<?php if (isset($attributes) && $attributes instanceof Illuminate\View\ComponentAttributeBag && $constructor = (new ReflectionClass(Illuminate\View\AnonymousComponent::class))->getConstructor()): ?>
<?php $attributes = $attributes->except(collect($constructor->getParameters())->map->getName()->all()); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $component->withAttributes([]); ?> // This line throws undefine variable $component
<table align="center" role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="700" style="margin: auto;" class="email-container">

...

Another wierd issue is only 1 view file is cached, layout.blade.php & footer.blade.php are not included
